# Intelligencia URL Rewrite Problem

Tags: regex, url, urlrewriter.net

I have created 2 url rewrite rules in my web.config that look like the following:

rewrite url="~/Products/(.+).aspx" to="~/Products.aspx?Cat=$1"

rewrite url="~/Products/(.+)/(.+).aspx" to="~/Products.aspx?Cat=$1&SubCat=$2"

If i type in Products/xyz.aspx it works perfectly but if i try a url that implements the second rule like Products/xyx/abc.aspx it passes both xyz and abc to the Cat and not the SubCat. Any ideas how i can get it to handle both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest removing all the matching on the "." symbol as it will make your matches a bit harder to predict. Instead use whatever character patterns cover your product categories and sub-categories.

```
rewrite url="~/Products/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).aspx" to="~/Products.aspx?Cat=$1"

rewrite url="~/Products/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9]+).aspx" to="~/Products.aspx?Cat=$1&SubCat=$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your regex non-greedy as:

```
rewrite url="~/Products/(.+?)/(.+).aspx" to="~/Products.aspx?Cat=$1&SubCat=$2"
                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because regular expression matching is *greedy*.  The `(.+)` in the first line matches as much as it can, including `xyz/abc`.  The quick fix for your problem is probably to change the first pattern to use `([^/]+)` instead (you may have to escape the `/` somehow depending on your environment).

Comment: Hi Ben, Could you possibly give me an example of what the url rewrite would look like as regular expressions aren't one of my strong points. Thanks